# When all jQuery promises returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am having an issue where I want to know when ALL of the jquery promises have returned. Is there a **clean** way of doing this via jQuery promises without having to do any loops to see what has been returned etc.

Something like this ...

```
$.when(function() {
   promiseOne();
   promiseTwo();
   promiseThree();
   promiseFour();
   promiseFive();
}).done(function() {
   alert("ALL DONE");
});
```

I know when is not supposed to have an anonymous function inside but it is to illustrate my point.

Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks

Comment: Quoting the docs for `$.when`: *in the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected.* Isn't that exactly what you need?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Thanks, may sound stupid but in my example promiseOne(), promiseTwo() each return promises, I would need to pass the function as an object (without ()) as parameters in the when ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass all promises into $.when as individual arguments:

```
$.when(
   promiseOne(),
   promiseTwo(),
   promiseThree(),
   promiseFour(),
   promiseFive()
).done(function() {
   alert("ALL DONE");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense in your code, try adding all of your promises to an array, then:

```
$.when.apply($, allPromises).done(callback);
```

Or even cleaner in my opinion, use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
$.when(...allPromises).done(callback);
```